# Issue with deleting action on a row in table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the following error which I believe to be due to swift 3 new syntax vs an older tutorial I am following, any idea how to correct the error so I can use the function?

> Cannot convert value of type '(UITableViewRowAction) -> ()' to expected argument type '(UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath) -> Void'

with this code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete")   { (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath: NSIndexPath) in
        print("delete me \(indexPath.row)")
    }
```

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40156490/5327882

Comment: thanks this worked after messing around with it for a bit

Answer (score 1):

Your handler isn't correct. It needs to be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete")   { (_ rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, _ indexPath: IndexPath) in
        print("delete me \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    return [deleteAction]
}
```