# How can I delete a row with native animation of a tableView by a button in custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to delete a table row by action from button in custom cell, using native tableView animations. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hi Renato and welcome to stack overflow. Could you please explain better what you want to do and show what code you have so far.

Comment: Search for delete cell tableview animation

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156274/deleting-a-row-from-a-uitableview-in-swift-3

Answer (score 0):

> I Found a good solution, using a custom delegate and
>   TableViewDataSource method!

**I had to work with Protocol in my custom cell Class, like this:**

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
   func didDelete(cell: MyCell)
}
```

**In my custom cell Class I made this:**

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

@IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     delegate?.didDelete(cell: self)
  }
}
```

**In my ViewController I made the delegates and data source implementation:**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch editingStyle {
        case .delete:
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at:[indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: MyCellDelegate {

    func didDelete(cell: MyCell) {

        guard let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }

        myArray?.remove(at: index.row)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: index)
    }
}
```