# Appllication crashes with self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Application part deletes the file but also crashes on error message

declared part

```
var FileContent = (try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath : newpath.first!))
var SingleUrl = newpath.first!
```

```
//MARK:- viewcontroller extension Deleting file from directory
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: SingleUrl + "/" + FileContent![indexPath.row])
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
```

the error message is............

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Comment: Reload the table view after deleting a row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting a Row from a UITableView in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156274/deleting-a-row-from-a-uitableview-in-swift-3)

Comment: start var names with small letter

Comment: You should delete element from the respective datasource(array) as well!

Comment: Check your number of rows in section method , you are returning wrong number of rows that's what the message shows. And one should first call  tableView.beginUpdates &  after updates tableView.EndUpdates.The original data model from which you are returning numberof Rows is not updated. That model is still returning the original number of rows (5) because you have not removed that item from that array

Comment: @Help No, one should **not** call `begin-/endUpdates` for a single delete operation. It's only for multiple simultaneous insert/delete/move operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete from the array not only the file

```
try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: singleUrl + "/" + fileContent![indexPath.row]) 
fileContent!.remove(at:indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```